# Unable to run "mvn verify clean --offline" in a fresh Maven installation

Tags: maven, rhel

I'm working on a linux (RHEL) box not connected to the internet. I currently have the "apache-maven-3.2.3-bin.tar.gz" from the maven-apache [download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

When I run "mvn verify clean --offline" in a terminal I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ABC 2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-=clean-plugin:jar:2.5 
          is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ................
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its 
        dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ................
[ERROR]
```

(I'm removing extraneous info. If you want me to add the flag -X or -e ask me to do so and I'll post the results. I didn't think they'd be useful.)

I followed the instructions on the download page to configure my box for "Unix-based Operating Systems" and converted my Eclipse 3.x RCP Application to a Maven Project, which created a pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.oirg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>data.git_repo.abc_repos</groupId>
  <artifactId>cem.abc</artifactId>
  <version>2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>RDC</name>

  <properties>
    <tycho-version>0.21.0</tycho-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEnconding>
  </properties>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>abc</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>offline</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>abc_repo</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>file:///data/git_repos/abc_repos/cem.abc</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>abc_repo</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>file:///data/git_repos/abc_repos/cem.abc</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      <snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    <pluginRepository>    
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resources>
        <directory>src<directory>
      </resources>
    <resources>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `-U` and `--offline` seem to be conflicting directions. -U is "Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories"

Comment: That would be a problem.............. but still, when I run "mvn verify clean --offline" it pukes with similar errors.

Comment: I don't think this will work at all because I need to download the jars for Maven, but I can't because that box doesn't have internet access, and it doesn't come in the `apache-maven-3.2.3-bin.tar.gz` file..... I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: The `.tar.gz` file is a very lightweight one - it's merely the maven distribution. Even the most basic of features will require plugins and they have to exist in your local maven repository (`~/.m2/`) if you want to run maven builds offline. Even then, for plugins/libraries that do not exist in your local repo, it has to talk to the corporate repo (usually on the intranet) and possibly the central repo (on the internet) depending on the needs.

Comment: Where I use --offline is on my development laptop. Earlier in the day I've run normal Maven commands that populate my local repo with the plugins I need (as described by @mystarrocks). Later, when I don't have access to the network, I can continue to develop because I have a populated repo. If I had an empty repo --offline would not work.

Comment: Maven distribution is only the core, and does not contain all the plugins needed to perform a proper build. So either connect that box, or package a working repo and put it inside that box local repo.

Comment: mvn dependency:go-offline

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared. Thank you everyone, for confirming what I learned! I'll make this work one way or another. I apologize for the silly/stupid question. @NielsBechNielsen that command will download all of the necessary jars from the central Maven repo, which I can't do.

Comment: Run the go-offline on a connected workstation and copy your .m2/repository to your offline maschine.. Then they would be available.

Answer (score 0):

To work off-line with Maven, you need a local Maven repository which has all the needed artifacts. Maven automatically downloads them when you are building without the `--offline` switch.

If you have a machine without Internet access, you can still build your project in the following way:

1. Build the on a machine with Internet access.
2. Copy the local Maven repository `~/.m2/repository/` from the on-line machine to the off-line machine.
3. Build the project with `--offline`.

Comment: That second step is harder than you'd imagine, which is why I've been trying to remove it. But, because it appears to be almost impossible, I've given up.